# how to apply a function to a certain portion of a filtered data in a data.table in r

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table and would like to do the following:

1. filter the data based on multiple conditions
2. apply a function to a "portion" of this filtered data on a single column
3. modify/update other columns corresponding to the same "portion" of
   the filtered data
4. modify/update the remaining portion of the other columns
5. all updates done inplace of the data.table to keep the same dimensions

Here is an example:
Data table:

```
dt <- data.table(ename = rep(c('a','b'),10),
                 tcode = rep(c(100,200,300,400),5),
                 tcdes = rep(c('EFG','HIJ','KLM','NGH'),5),
                 hours = rep(c(8),20))
# output
# ename tcode tcdes hours
# 1:     a   100   EFG     8
# 2:     b   200   HIJ     8
# 3:     a   300   KLM     8
# 4:     b   400   NGH     8
# 5:     a   100   EFG     8
# 6:     b   200   HIJ     8
# 7:     a   300   KLM     8
# 8:     b   400   NGH     8
# 9:     a   100   EFG     8
# 10:     b   200   HIJ     8
# 11:     a   300   KLM     8
# 12:     b   400   NGH     8
# 13:     a   100   EFG     8
# 14:     b   200   HIJ     8
# 15:     a   300   KLM     8
# 16:     b   400   NGH     8
# 17:     a   100   EFG     8
# 18:     b   200   HIJ     8
# 19:     a   300   KLM     8
# 20:     b   400   NGH     8

#1. Filter the data by multiple conditions:

dt[(ename == 'b'& tcode == 400),]

# output
#   ename tcode tcdes hours
#1:     b   400   NGH     8
#2:     b   400   NGH     8
#3:     b   400   NGH     8
#4:     b   400   NGH     8
#5:     b   400   NGH     8
```

2. The function I would like to apply is:

   a. take a certain % (portion) of this filtered data (say 70% which will gives first 3.5 rows - so flooring this value to get 3 rows (rows: 1 to 3))

   b. multiply the hours column by 0.7 for this portion
3. Modify the tcode and tcdes columns for this portion of data to:

   a. tcode = 230

   b. tcdes = "JKL"
4. Modify the tcode and tcdes columns of the remaining portion (2 rows: 4 & 5) of the filtered data to:

   a. tcode = 340

   b. tcdes = "BVH"

```
5. The filtered result should look like:

dt[(ename == 'b'& tcode == 230 & tcode == 340),]

# output
#   ename tcode tcdes hours
#1:     b   230   JKL     5.6
#2:     b   230   JKL     5.6
#3:     b   230   JKL     5.6
#4:     b   340   BVH     8
#5:     b   340   BVH     8
```

I am new to R as a whole and will greatly appreciate the help. I have tried to use the lapply() with .SD, .SDcols and :=, `:=` but cannot get the function to be applied to a portion and maintain the full data.table.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could create a `list` or `data.table` with the values and then either do a join or use `Map` to replace the values

```
library(data.table)
newdt <- data.table(tcode = c(230, 340), tcdes = c("JKL", "BVH"), hours = c(0.7, 1))
dt[(ename == 'b'& tcode == 400),  names(newdt) := {
         i1 <- as.integer(0.7 * .N)
         i2 <- rep(1:2, c(i1, .N - i1))
          Map(function(x, y, z) if(z) x[i2] * y[i2] else y[i2],
             .SD, newdt, c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE))
       }, .SDcols = names(newdt)]



dt[(ename == 'b'& tcode == 230 | tcode == 340)]
#   ename tcode tcdes hours
#1:     b   230   JKL   5.6
#2:     b   230   JKL   5.6
#3:     b   230   JKL   5.6
#4:     b   340   BVH   8.0
#5:     b   340   BVH   8.0
```

Comment: Many many thanks for this akrun. I am in the process of implementing this in the bigger data.table and will update this comment once done.

Comment: It worked... many thanks.. just threw a warning on the actual data.table:Coerced double RHS to integer to match the type of the target column (column 11 named 'tcode'). The RHS values contain no fractions so would be more efficiently created as integer. Consider using R's 'L' postfix (typeof(0L) vs typeof(0)) to create constants as integer and avoid this warning. Wrapping the RHS with as.integer() will avoid this warning too but it's better if possible to create the RHS as integer in the first place so that the cost of the coercion can be avoided.

Comment: @mraj33  if that is the case, you may need to first convert the that specific column to `integer` or `round` because theere is type matching